# Any difference between loop around transaction, or loop in transaction?

Tags: database, transactions

What are the differences between these two ways of doing many little jobs and committing the work of each to the database:

```
for i = 1 to n
    begin transaction
        do job i
        commit transaction  
    end transaction
end loop
```

and

```
begin transaction
    for i = 1 to n
        do job i
        commit transaction  
    end loop
end transaction
```

which approach is better to use?

I am thinking specifically in terms of locks, transaction log size, performance.  And if the type of database matters, I am thinking MySQL.